# Is there an open source tool that automatically generates test cases for legacy code?

Tags: python, unit-testing, fortran, legacy-code

I recently stumbled over this (aged) article:

http://imranontech.com/2007/01/04/unit-testing-the-final-frontier-legacy-code/

where the author allegedly wrote a perl script to automatically generate test cases. 
His strategy went like this (cited):

1. Read in the header files I gave it.
2. Extracted the function prototypes.
3. Gave me the list of functions it found and let me pick
   which ones I wanted to create unit tests for.
4. It then created a dbx
   (Solaris debugger) script which would break-point every time the
   selected function was called, save the variables that were passed to
   it and then continue until the function returned at which point it
   would save the return value.
5. Run the executable under the dbx
   script, and which point I proceeded to use the application as
   normal, and just ran through lots of use cases which I thought would
   go through the code in question and especially cases where I thought
   it would hit edge cases in the functions I want to create unit tests
   for.
6. The perl script then took all of the example runs, stripped out
   duplicates, and then autogenerated a C file containing unit tests
   for each of the examples (i.e pass in the input data and verify the
   return value is the same as in the example run) Compiled/Linked/Ran
   the unit tests and threw away ones which failed (i.e. get rid of
   inputs which cause the function to behave non-deterministically)

I have a lot of legacy code of all kinds in the languages Python and Fortran. The article is from 2007. Is there anything like this implemented in current Unit testing frameworks?

How would i go about writing such a script?

Answer (score 0):

Very C-like. Also, OS dependent, I think (Solaris debugger)? I'd say you should look at "record/capture and playback" tools, though somehow I think the "generate" part never really took off.

[Python's testing tools taxonomy](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonTestingToolsTaxonomy#Web_Testing_Tools) would be a great place to start. I'd say you either record your way through application using Selenium or [Dogtail](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/Automation/DogtailTutorial). The link takes you right to that section, Web testing tools, but check others as well: fuzzy testing is a technique similar to [Golden Master](http://craftedsw.blogspot.com/2012/11/testing-legacy-code-with-golden-master.html), which sometimes may help with legacy apps, and is a "record / playback" technique. Feathers calls such tests "characterization" test, for they characterize legacy system's behaviours.

Very good point in article you cite:

> Have a look at your own source code repository and see which
>   functions/classes have had the most bugfix checkins applied, 80% of
>   bugfixes tend to be made to about 20% of the code. There’s sound logic
>   behind this – often that 20% of the code is poorly written with dozens
>   or hundreds of “special case” hacks.

This is where I'd actually start. Have you got these parts identified? Simple Git/SVB log usage scripts and coverage tools section from the taxonomy would come in handy with this.

Unfortunately more than that I can't help you - my Python experience is limited and Fortran - non-existing.